# What are sets of values in inequality?

Tags: inequality

I have this question on my study guide:

> Bill's bank account has less than 7 dollars in it. Which set of values makes the inequality $b < 7$ true?

What does the "set of values" mean here, and how do I get it from the inequality $b<7$?

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking you to indicate all of the values you can assign to $b$ that make the statement "$b<7$" a true statement. The phrase "set of values" means the collection or aggregation of all the values of interest. This is sometimes called the "solution set" for the inequality.

In this case, the set you are looking for happens to be an interval on the number line, so it contains all numbers in a certain range -- all of the numbers that are less than $7$. Using interval notation, this is usually written $$(-\infty,7)$$ or sometimes $$]-\infty,7[$$ Note that the endpoint $7$ is not meant to be included in this interval.

Answer (score 0):

The question is about Bill's bank account. The solution set for the inequality, $b<7$ has a lower bound of $0$ because money held on deposit is always positive (a credit value) never negative (a debit). The solution set is therefore all values on the interval, $[0, 7)$

$[0, 7)$ is interval notation which means all values between $0$ and $7$, inclusive of lower endpoint $0$ but exclusive of upper endpoint $7$.